# How to increase the duration of STS credentials validity from one hour?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-sts

I am going through this AWS doc about temporary credentials, and I have come across this, about the duration of them:

> The GetSessionToken action must be called by using the long-term AWS
>   security credentials of the AWS account or an IAM user.
>
> Credentials that are created by IAM users are valid for the duration
>   that you specify, from 900 seconds (15 minutes) up to a maximum of
>   129600 seconds (36 hours), with a default of 43200 seconds (12 hours);
>   credentials that are created by using account credentials can range
>   from 900 seconds (15 minutes) up to a maximum of 3600 seconds (1
>   hour), with a default of 1 hour.

**So, what is the difference between `created by IAM users` and `created by using account credentials`?**

I am creating my temporary credentials using STS via boto3, and they are being expired within an hour. How do I make them be valid for the 36 hours which is mentioned here, via boto3?

Answer (score 3):

The maximum duration is related to **the credentials used to make the call to STS**.

If you use your Root Credentials (where you login with an email address), it is considered an Account Credential. You **should not typically use root credentials** since they are *too powerful* and cannot be restricted. You should always create an IAM User and use it for your day-to-day work on AWS. This allows the credentials to be restricted or revoked, which provides much better security control.

Therefore:

- If you call STS with Root Credentials, the limit is 1 hour
- If you call STS with IAM User Credentials, the limit is 36 hours

Comment: Important: You cannot call assume-role by using AWS root account credentials; access is denied. You must use credentials for an IAM user or an IAM role to call assume-role  , refer: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html

Comment: Correct. However, using Root Credentials works fine for `get-session-token` (but isn't good practice).