# Why are the STS credentials getting expired within 45 minutes?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, aws-sts

I have this setup where my Ansible playbook runs, which runs an ML script which takes around 3-4 hours for execution, and some AWS tasks running after the ML script.

So, I am running a background `updatecredentials.py` python file which updates both the `/home/ubuntu/.aws/config` and the file from where my AWS takes credentials from.
This file runs every **45** minutes.

The updates are as follows:

For the first instance of the run, the `stat` of the config file is as follows:

```
  File: ‘/home/ubuntu/.aws/config’
  Size: 480         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: ca01h/51713d    Inode: 275461      Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/  ubuntu)   Gid: ( 1000/  ubuntu)
Access: 2017-08-09 09:53:20.600856000 +0000
Modify: 2017-08-09 09:53:18.804856000 +0000
Change: 2017-08-09 09:53:18.804856000 +0000
```

For the second instance, it is:

```
  File: ‘/home/ubuntu/.aws/config’
  Size: 480         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: ca01h/51713d    Inode: 275461      Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/  ubuntu)   Gid: ( 1000/  ubuntu)
Access: 2017-08-09 12:10:29.072856000 +0000
Modify: 2017-08-09 10:38:18.892856000 +0000
Change: 2017-08-09 10:38:18.892856000 +0000
```

So, the `nohup` is working.  However, I get the error in the `.err` file of the nohup code as:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ExpiredToken) when calling the AssumeRole operation: The security token included in the request is expired
```

And when I did `stat` to the `creds.err` file, it shows:

```
  File: ‘creds.err’
  Size: 594         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: ca01h/51713d    Inode: 275463      Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/  ubuntu)   Gid: ( 1000/  ubuntu)
Access: 2017-08-09 12:04:49.952856000 +0000
Modify: 2017-08-09 11:23:18.940856000 +0000
Change: 2017-08-09 11:23:18.940856000 +0000
 Birth: -
```

**Does this mean that my STS[/temporary] credentials expired within 45 minutes?**

Comment: Your credentials should expire in an hour. That's the default and the maximum.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I know that.  That's exactly why I'm asking this question :)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45539658/how-to-increase-the-duration-of-sts-credentials-validity-from-one-hour?rq=1